# Check if an int/str is in the list and its location. Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Say that I have a list that looks something like the this :

```
MyList = [1,2,3,4,5,"z","x","c","v","b"]
```

Now the users inputs : "5z1b3". How would you replace each int/str with its location in the list. I'm thinking of using something like this:

```
for x in MyList.... if located in list, replace with letter/number with its location.
```

Not entirely sure how to do it though. Help would be much appreciated.

edit::::: It's something I'm working on and I must use both ints and strs in the list. Also I lied about the output I need. Thanks for mentioning it avarnert. commas between each letter/number in the output would make it work for me. Any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please post the expected output for the given inputs? Also, what is `the list` in your pseudocode?

Comment: Note that the character `"5"` does not exist anywhere in your list. The fact that the number `5` does is irrelevant; `"5" != 5` in Python.

Comment: Input would be: 5z1b3, no brackets. I'm expecting the output to be: 45092

Comment: So if `MyList` had one more element in it, like adding `"a"` at the end, and the input were `5z1a3`, you'd expect `450102`? Or maybe `450A2` in hex or something?

Comment: Why do you have both ints and strings in your list?

Comment: You should really edit this new information into your post

Comment: It's something I'm working on and I must use both ints and strs in the list. Also I lied about the output I need. Thanks for mentioning it avarnert. commas between each letter/number in the output would make it work for me. Any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: I really doubt you need both ints and strings. It sounds like you'd want `'5'` instead of `5`.

Comment: It's OK if you must use both ints and strs in the list… but, given that the string `"5"` isn't anywhere in `MyList`, what do you want to happen? How is `"5z1b3"` supposed to be processed?

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[MyList.index(c) for c in inputstring]
```

This'll have to scan through `MyList` for each entry; you could optimize that quite a bit by using a dictionary indexing from character to position; this has the added advantage we can ensure we only have strings as well:

```
index = {str(c): i for i, c in enumerate(MyList)}
[index[c] for c in inputstring]
```

If you then need a formatted string, turn the indices to strings and join the final output:

```
index = {str(c): str(i) for i, c in enumerate(MyList)}
','.join([index[c] for c in inputstring])
```

Comment: I can see this breaking for multiple occurrences of some `c`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: and what would the expected behaviour be in that case?

Comment: No, since the dict will overwrite to the last occurrence. I would go with list/tuple values that hold _all_ occurrence indices. Then again, I don't really know what OP is asking for - the question is quite underspecified

Comment: Try `{c:[i for i,char in mystr if char==c] for c in mystr}`. It's O(n^2), but complete. A for-loop with a `defaultdict` would be linear, though not as compact

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: But the OP asked for _the_ index in the list, not a list of all of them. His sample doesn't have any duplicates. If you give him `[3]` when his later code is expecting `3`, it's going to break that later code. And even worse if you give him `[3, 8]`.

Comment: @abarnert: you're right. Hence why I said that the question is underspecified. I'm still waiting on clarifications on the question

Comment: looks like OP wants `''.join(str(MyList.index(c)) for c in inputstring)`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: "Also I lied about the output I need… between each letter/number in the output would make it work for me." So it's `','.join(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about using the list.index() method. See below for example:

```
MyList = [MyList.index(chr) for chr in user_input]
```

EDIT:
This however assumes that each character from the user input will be found in MyList, and also that each character in MyList will appear only once.